# Cron Job working on MySQL UPDATE but not on SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a cron job running every 5 minutes pointing at this script. If I manually visit the .php page everything runs as expected. However, when the cron runs, it produces an empty `$map_clusters` array, but at the same time the cron job does update the latter $sys query successfully so I know the database connection is working fine with the cron query. So for some reason the cron job is not successfully running the initial SELECT query. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM map_clusters WHERE project_ref = 'pjm' ";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $map_clusters[] = $row;
}

//process $map_clusters here

$sys = "UPDATE system SET do_update_map = '0' ";
mysqli_query($connect, $sys);
```

Comment: We can't tell how you know it's empty, since you missed the processing part and there's nothing which would output anything from the code shown. Nor we can see the source data of the database, or be sure there's definitely matching data in the DB when the job runs. Please provide a [mre] of the issue. It does seem very strange. No doubt there'll be an explanatiob but what you've posted so far isn't sufficient to be able to see any problems.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment made me dig further and I found the issue, which in turn raised a whole other issue. I had an `if (file_exists())` in the process and it was failing b/c I assume the cron needed a full path. I have now tried `if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$icon_name))` which is still not working. But this might be better for a new question